# (How) Can I use boost::spirit X3 without installing the full boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Is it possible to use boost::spirit x3 without installing the full boost library? I am aware that the repository for the module is available [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit), but I don't really know how to use the code or which files to include. How do I get startet, it this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer here is: use BCP (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html).

However, that page explains quite aptly how and why this will result in a very fat selection of dependencies.

So, maybe follow their advice:

> If you want to figure out which Boost headers are being used by your specific compiler then the best way to find out is to prepocess the code and scan the output for boost header includes. You should be aware that the result will be very platform and compiler specific, and may not contain all the headers needed if you so much as change a compiler switch (for example turn on threading support).